# Remove "Title" column from list default view using power shell command

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, script

I have created the custom list with the default view using power shell script.Also added the required columns.but I don't want to show the "Title" column in All items view.How to handle this using power shell script ?

Answer (score 5):

Something like the following:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity 'http://www.spsite.com/subsite'
$List = $web.Lists['MyList']
$column = $List.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName('Title')
$column.Hidden = $true
$column.ShowInDisplayForm = $false
$column.ShowInViewForms = $false
$column.ShowInEditForm = $false
$column.ShowInListSettings = $false
$column.Update()

# To delete the column, simply add the following row
$List.Fields.Delete($column)
```

Comment: This code helps to just hide the title field in add new item page.I need to remove the "Title" in list default view.please suggest an idea.

Comment: @GokulPgp See my updated answer